# CreateJS Low Memory crash on mobile safari IOS

Tags: ios, iphone, safari, createjs

I am developing a game with the CreateJS Framework.

The game is working fine on a desktop but the game crashes in mobile Safari on IOS 7 with an iphone 4. The iphone log (general->about->diagnostics&usage) shows an error "LowMemory" after it crashes.

I started XCODE activity monitor to see what happens to the memory. During the game the real memory usage of mobile Safari increases to 132mb and the virtual memory up to 770mb before it crashes.

Can somebody help me out with some hints on what is going on? I don't now exactly how to interpret the memory values. Is there a memory leak? 132 mb seems oke to me? Is VM to much?

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide further information, like an example or at least some code or description what you're doing in createJS (image heavy app? pure paintings? etc..). You can also try to profile with chrome first: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/heap-profiling

Answer (score 0):

Found a memory leak; some game objects were not cleared from memory.